# issue in python list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings in my python application. Each string represents a dictionary. Here is an example input:

```
['{"ID": "1234", "Name": "AAA", "DEPT": "CCC", "SRC": "DL"}', '{"ID": "1234", "NAME": "AAA", "DEPT": "CCC", "SRC": "SNF"}']
```

I need to convert these strings to their equivalent dictionaries. The output should be like:

```
[{"ID": "1234", "Name": "AAA", "DEPT": "CCC", "SRC": "DL"}, {"ID": "1234", "NAME": "AAA", "DEPT": "CCC", "SRC": "SNF"}]
```

Comment: This looks like JSON‽ You want to JSON-decode every element in the list‽

Comment: You don't have to "remove single quotes", you have to _parse_.

Comment: yes I need to remove single quotes (') for every element

Comment: No, you want to turn a string representation of a dict into an actual dict. By *parsing* the string using the appropriate parser.

Comment: There are no single quotes to remove; that's just part of the string representation of the elements of your list. You are confusing your data with how your data is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

```
import json
l = ... # your list
res = [json.loads(s) for s in l]
```